# Sencha Touch: Passing store to checkbox?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

How to create a list of checkboxes by passing a store?

Something like :

```
items: [{
       xtype: 'checkboxfield',
       id:    {id},
       name : {name},
       label:  {label},
       value:  {value},
       store:  App.store.checkboxStore
}]
```

Well, I have achieved it by iterating over store and adding checkboxes to view. Though, if you have any easier way to do it please share.

```
var catStore = App.stores.profileStore; *<<YOUR STORE>>*
        for (i = 0; i < catStore.getCount(); i++) {

            App.views.destinationsView.add({
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                    label: catStore.getAt(i).data.label,
                    value: catStore.getAt(i).data.value,
                    name: catStore.getAt(i).data.name,

                }]
            });
        }
```

Comment: I did it this way as well.  I'm now working on saving/loading to and from a store.  I haven't got that working yet.  I have radiobuttons working but not checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to generate the checkboxes without looping through the store, you can use a grid with a checkbox selection model, which will automatically render the checkboxes. The grid can be styled as you wish, for example to hide borders.

Here's a [Sencha example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/row-editing.html) of a grid with checkboxes (you can put them in whatever column you like.)